# Stopping the "javax.swing.timer" won't pause the animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer

I have created an animation with the `javax.swing.timer` and it seems to work fine.

However, the animation is going on forever, so I decided to add the `timer.stop()` method.

Here's a small piece of the code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(xGrid, 200, 50, 50);

    t.start();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if (xGrid >= 350) {

        t.stop();
    }

    xGrid++;
    repaint();
}
```

I'm expecting the animation to stop when the circle reaches the position of (350, 200).

But it doesn't. When I run the program, it just outputs the same as before, with the animation being slightly slower.

This is quite confusing, can anyone please help?

Any help would be tremendously appreciated,

Comment: Please provide a runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we can reproduce your behavior.

Comment: Why are you calling `start()` in `paintComponent()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `repaint()` in your `actionPerformed()` implementation schedules a later call to `paintComponent()`, but your implementation of `paintComponent()` then calls `start()` on the `Timer`. This creates an infinite loop that keeps the `Timer` running. At a minimum, remove the call to `start()` from `paintComponent()`.

Comment: For more specific guidance, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes, the program is running correctly now. I shouldn't really trust any random tutorials on youtube :)